# Returning reference to temporary error when remodeling from T ** to vec<vec<T>>

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I encountered an error that happend in my proxy class for `operator []`. It was checking if index is in range, and worked fine when I implemented my class template with `T** values.`

But I felt like change whole implementation to `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`. Everything is fine, expect said `operator[]`.

Matrix class operator(s)

```
//***************************************************************************
template <typename T>
X_Proxy<T> Matrix<T>::operator [](const size_t& j)
{
    if(j >= y)
        ERROR_MSG(Y_OUT_RANGE);
    return X_Proxy<T>(inner[j], x);
}

//***************************************************************************
template <typename T>
const X_Proxy<T> Matrix<T>::operator [](const size_t& j) const
{
    if(j >= y)
        ERROR_MSG(Y_OUT_RANGE);
    return X_Proxy<T>(inner[j], x);
}
//***************************************************************************
```

Proxy class template definition:

```
template <typename T>
struct X_Proxy
{
    X_Proxy(std::vector<T> PTR, const size_t X) : x_ptr(PTR), x(X) {}
    T& operator [] (size_t pos);
    const T& operator [] (size_t pos) const;
    std::vector<T>& x_ptr;
    const size_t& x;
};
```

Proxy class operator(s):

```
//***************************************************************************
template <typename T>
T& X_Proxy<T>::operator [] (size_t pos)
{
    if (pos > x-1)
        Matrix<T>::ERROR_MSG(Matrix<T>::X_OUT_RANGE);
    return x_ptr[pos];
}
//***************************************************************************
template <typename T>
const T& X_Proxy<T>::operator [] (size_t pos) const
{
    if (pos > x-1)
        Matrix<T>::ERROR_MSG(Matrix<T>::X_OUT_RANGE);
    return x_ptr[pos];  // <--- the error line
}

//***************************************************************************
```

Matrix error function:

```
template <typename T>
void Matrix<T>::ERROR_MSG(const int& MSG)
{
    std::cerr << info[MSG] << std::endl;
    exit(MSG);
}
```

Compilation error:

```
..\matrix.h:47: error: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
         return x_ptr[pos];
                         ^
```

What could go wrong with our lovely template library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `X_Proxy` constructor is storing a reference to a temporary:

```
X_Proxy(std::vector<T> PTR, const size_t X) : x_ptr(PTR), x(X) {}
```

Here, `PTR` is a local temporary, and `x_ptr` is an lvalue reference:

```
std::vector<T>& x_ptr;
```

This isn't standard C++, so it shouldn't even compile. But your compiler allows it, leaving you with a dangling reference.

Perhaps you want to store a reference to a valid vector:

```
X_Proxy(std::vector<T>& PTR, const size_t X) : x_ptr(PTR), x(X) {}
                      ^
```

This will work as long as the vector referred to by `PTR` outlives the `X_Proxy` instance.

Comment: Well I found it out just a moment ago, but when I change argument to `std::vector<T>& PTR`, I get like 40 conversion errors... Like it struggles with consts. The thing is that `Matrix operator[] (...) const;` won't be accepted as non-const argument.

Comment: @BlackMoses Maybe you're passing a reference to `const`. Anyway, that sounds like another question, requiring a different MCVE.

Comment: I have to pass it const, well, not I but compiler, for objects of `Matrix` declared `const`.

Comment: @BlackMoses Sure. And that is another question. You may need to use `eturn X_Proxy<const T>(inner[j], x);` for the `const` overloads.

Comment: `Error: no matching function for call to 'X_Proxy<const char>::X_Proxy(const value_type&, const size_t&)'
     return X_Proxy<const T>(inner[j], x);`                      `note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const value_type {aka const std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >}' to 'std::vector<const char, std::allocator<const char> >&'`

Comment: I will post new question about this :)